# How to pass enum parameter from Combobox to another class (winform)

Tags: .net, c, enums

I need help passing the selected Enum value from Combobox(cbShowVal) to another class.

```
class A{
//Enum:
public enum myDisplayOptions{Test1, Test2, Test3}

//Combox binding:
cbShowVal.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DisplayOptions));
}

class B{
private int newVal = 0;

public int GetNumOfSeats(myDisplayOptions ch){
swith(ch)
{
case myDisplayOptions.Test1:
newVal = 100;
break;

case myDisplayOptions.Test2:
newVal = 200;
break;

case myDisplayOptions.Test3:
newVal = 300;
break;

}
return newVal;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you convert the string back into the enum

```
myDisplayOptions option = 
    (myDisplayOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(myDisplayOptions), cbShowVal.SelectedValue);
```

and then

```
B b = new B();
int seats = b.GetNumOfSeats(option);
```